# CoordinatorLayout ViewPager , контент внутри ViewPager должен зависеть внешнего координатора

Tags: android, coordinator-layout

Лишние элементы исключил из кода.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|snap"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Вот внутри ViewPager находятся фрагменты , вот их разметка

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorQuestionBackground"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/question_tv"
            layout="@layout/question_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question_image" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/question_image"
            layout="@layout/question_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="145dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup_answer"
            layout="@layout/radiogroup_answer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question_tv" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/hint"
            layout="@layout/hint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/next_question"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radiogroup_answer"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/hint_button"
            layout="@layout/hint_button"
            android:layout_width="340dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radiogroup_answer"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="top"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/next_question"
            layout="@layout/next_question_button"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/next_question_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/next_question_height"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="top" />
```

Тут две проблемы : 1) во корневом FrameLayout лежит ImageView, по клику этот ImageView становится видимым, маштабируется, но находится не по середине, он отступает вниз ровно на значение высоты Toolbar . 2) В ConstraintLayout есть @+id/hint_button он должен размещаться внизу экрана. Его видно если Toolbar убрать с экрана, а если его опустить он уходит за экран. А я хочу сделать его поведение таким, чтобы он оставался на экране. Но на мои попытки работать с app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="top" не успешны, реакции вообще никакой не вижу

Comment: 1. при масштабировании сделайте смещение ImageView на высоту toolbar через translationY (можно с использованием анимации). 2. Хинт можно поднимать в слушателе AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener, когда его начинают опускать, тогда он не будет уходить за экран.

Comment: Хотел более изящное решение, не трогая код анимации и масштабирования. Hint лежит внизу экрана с отступом снизу, когда toolbar становится подвижен, размер корневого вью становится 1080, естественно hint окажется за пределами экрана. Можно сделать так как вы предложили, но я нашел более изящный способ. Сейчас опубликую свой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот он волшебный класс, который учитывает момент, когда опускается `toolbar` и высота корневого вью, которая лежит в `ViewPager`, меняется в соответствии с тем опущен `toolbar` или нет.
Это кастомный `Behavior` применяется вот так к `ViewPager`

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="yourPackage.FixScrollingFooterBehavior" />
```

И сам код:

```
 public class FixScrollingFooterBehavior extends AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior {

    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;

    public FixScrollingFooterBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public FixScrollingFooterBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {

        if (appBarLayout == null) {
            appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) dependency;
        }

        final boolean result = super.onDependentViewChanged(parent, child, dependency);
        final int bottomPadding = calculateBottomPadding(appBarLayout);
        final boolean paddingChanged = bottomPadding != child.getPaddingBottom();
        if (paddingChanged) {
            child.setPadding(
                    child.getPaddingLeft(),
                    child.getPaddingTop(),
                    child.getPaddingRight(),
                    bottomPadding);
            child.requestLayout();
        }
        return paddingChanged || result;
    }


    // Calculate the padding needed to keep the bottom of the view pager content at the same location on the screen.
    private int calculateBottomPadding(AppBarLayout dependency) {
        final int totalScrollRange = dependency.getTotalScrollRange();
        return totalScrollRange + dependency.getTop();
    }
}
```